# How could I design circuit to make filter?

Tags: filter, circuit-design

In most books, it just has an image and said "this is bandpass filter" and that's all. Sometimes they explain why this is bandpass filter with graph or something.

However, what I really want to know is how to think those kind of design with value of 
components like \$C = 220\text{nF}\$, \$R = 100\text{k}\Omega\$, etc. How to set those specific values to each component?

Below is an example of my thinking how to design bandpass filter. Is it correct?

[image: Schematic]

Comment: You're missing the load.

Answer (score 2):

> How to set those specific values to each component?

With a little bit of phasor algebra, the voltage across \$R_2\$ is given by

$$V_{R2} = V_{in}\frac{j\omega R_2C_2}{1 - \omega^2R_1R_2C_1C_2 + j\omega(R_1C_1 + R_1C_2 + R_2C_2)}$$

This *is* a bandpass filter since output goes to zero as the frequency goes to zero and as the frequency goes to infinity.

The center frequency is

$$\omega_0 = \frac{1}{\sqrt{R_1R_2C_1C_2}}$$

The bandwidth is

$$B = \frac{1}{R_1C_1} + \frac{1}{R_2C_1} + \frac{1}{R_2C_2}$$

and the mid-band gain is

$$A_0 = \frac{R_2C_2}{R_1C_1 + R_1C_2 + R_2C_2} = \frac{1}{1 + \frac{R_1}{R_2}(1 + \frac{C_1}{C_2})}$$

But you have four degrees of freedom (four component values) to chose so there are infinity of combinations that give the same center frequency, bandwidth and mid-band gain.

You can reduce the degrees of freedom to three by, for example, specifying that

$$C_1 = C_2 = C$$

Now there is only one combination of \$R_1, R_2, C\$ for a given \$\omega_0, B, A_0\$

$$\omega_0 = \frac{1}{\sqrt{R_1R_2C^2}}$$

$$B = \frac{1}{R_1C} + \frac{2}{R_2C}$$

$$A_0 = \frac{1}{1 + 2\frac{R_1}{R_2}}$$

Answer (score 0):

Alfred Centauri has shown to you how to design this filter to meet your constraints. 
I'd add that another way to reduce degree of freedom is to make considerations about your load. Contrary to your comment to Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams, I don't consider \$R_2\$ as a load, because if you remove "your load", well you don't have a band-pass filter anymore. Instead your load \$R_L\$ will be in parallel to \$R_2\$. If your load is resistive, to grant that the load doesn't alter the response of your filter, you have to impose that \$R_2<<R_L\$. For instance if you knwow the minimum value of your load \$R_{L,min}\$ you can choose \$R_2=R_{L,min}/10\$ or smaller.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to verify the bandpass properties by visual inspection only:

- C2 blocks very low frequencies (includingDC),
- C1 has a very low impedance for "high" frequencies (short for infinite).

As a special case, this bandpass circuit can be used for equal components R1=R2 and C1=C2. In this case the center fequency is wo=1/RC and the midband "gain" is 1/3. It is to be noted that this bandpass has exactly the same properties as the well-known WIEN bandpass (series connection of R and C and R||C).

However, one should know that the selectivity of this passive RC bandpass is rather poor because the quality factor Q=Fo/B (B: bandwidh) never exceeds 0.5 (0.333 for equal components). For higher Q values you need LC resonance or active RC filters.

Answer (score 0):

Note that, the generic transfer function for this RC band-pass filter includes the term R1C2 on denominator, representing the "loading effect". See figure below:
[image: Loading effect]

When R2 >> R1 or when there is a buffer (eg op. amp based) between the two stages, that term vanishes. The net effect is the complete transfer function would be given by the product of individual transfer function for each stage (low-pass and high-pass):

[image: No loading effect]